# Accessing App Engine Dev server through unit tests

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to write a simple integration test that spins up a dev appengine server and an HTTP Client that queries the spun up server.  Here is the code snippet:

```
inst, err := aetest.NewInstance(nil)
check(err)
defer inst.Close()

var req http.Request 
req, err = inst.NewRequest("GET", "/my/endpoint", nil)
check(err)

ctx := appengine.NewContex(req)
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
_, err = client.Do(req)
check(err)
```

This code snippet returns an error on the line client.Do.  From what I've debugged, this is because the request's URL only contains "/my/endpoint" and not the entire localhost:port information.  In this particular case I cannot use the hardcoded port 8080 because the aetest framework starts the test on the first ununsed port it can find.

Is there a way to programmatically determine the host:port information of the appengine server that was started by aetest framework?

Comment: Just a thought from a different angle:  Are you sure there is no way to control or force the port that the aetest framework uses?    That seems like it would be easiest approach in my mind.

Comment: Yes, that approach came to mind.  The problem is that I would be repeating a lot of what aetest already does like: figuring out unused-ips, starting up server as a subprocess, rerouting and capturing logs to figure out server startup.  I was hoping to avoid all of this if possible.   It is silly that aetest does not expose this externally for people to reuse. :-(

Comment: Any solution to this problem?